# image upload on mobile web app fails because lack of memory

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

i've created a web mobile app using jquery mobile, and django, and i encountered a problem uploading captured pictures from my mobile phone to the server due to lack of memory (exact error in android's chrome : "unable to complete previous operation low memory upload image")

i fear that the smartphone's pictures are to big that it does not have enough space to hold it in the memory.

The only solution i can think of is - resizing the image on client side, but i could not find any easy way of doing so (including external javascript libraries)

my specific input in the html:

```
            <input accept="image/*" data-clear-btn="false" data-role="none" id="pictureUpload" name="image" type="file" />
```

I Would appreciate some help

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found the solution. But you can try walking around by clear Chrome cache.